# Used xrandr to rotate monitor but cannot reverse it after deleting script

Tags: xorg, boot, xrandr

I following a guide to have my tablet (Samsung ativ 700t running ubuntu 12.10 Gnome3) invert the screen 180 on login

I place a script file in `/etc/X11/Session.d/45custom-script`.

Contents of file: (going by memory)

```
  # I cannot remember if I had #!/bin/bash here at first but I'm betting no
  xrandr -o half
  xsetwacom set-prop 9 rotate 2
  xsetwacom set-prop 9 area 100 200 25000 14000 # numbers approximated
```

On the next boot this rotated the monitor correctly but not the stylus input (device 9).

I then delete the xrandr line to just test the xsetwacom but on the next boot it was still flipped (login screen was normal).

Then I did a bunch of things to attempt to fix it

- changed the xrandr to `xrandr -o none`
- changed the file name to `95custom-script` and `invert-screen` removed the file completely
- made sure to delete the 'filename~' files that gedit created
- removed the xsetwacom lines
- removed and added `#!/bin/bash` and `#!/bin/sh` to the top

My only theory is that the command was copied somewhere else and will not change again.

Comment: Did you put it in `~/.xinitrc`  or something similar?

Comment: No, was i suppose to?

Comment: I mean if you put it there before, then you may have to remove them, otherwise those setting will be applied every time you r login.

Comment: I only messed with the Session.d folder. My entire process of what I tried is in the question. I did nothing outside of what is mentioned above. If I am suppose to do something with the ~/.xinitrc could you explain, I have no idea what to do.